# How to stick/freeze an svg header to top

Tags: javascript, css, svg, google-visualization

In google timeline chart, there's a trick that brings the header (dates) to top.
How do I freeze that header so it stays visible when scrolling down vertically. Similar to freeze row in excel.

```
 function bring_date_header_up() {
    var g = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].getElementsByTagName("g")[1];
    document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].parentNode.style.top = '80px';
    document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].style.overflow = 'visible';
    var height = Number(g.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].getAttribute('y')) + 25;
    g.setAttribute('transform','translate(38,-'+height+')');
    g = null;
  }
```

Here's an example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJzxzj

Comment: You could leverage the power of CSS `position: "sticky"`. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: However, if you could share the rest of your code that would be ideal.

Comment: @MattPengelly just did

Comment: @MattPengelly if I try the style "position: sticky" on the parent node, it just disappears.

Comment: yep, it doesnt look like position sticky will play well with the transformations doing on

Comment: @MattPengelly any way to add the position directly in the transformation?  Something like -    g.setAttribute('transform','translate(38,-'+height+')','position: sticky');   ?

Comment: No I don't think that will have the intended effect. I tried looking at it actually but am not familiar with the google-visualization api

Comment: You could possibly clone the row and add it above the container...

Comment: @WhiteHat thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to do just that now but I can't seem to find a way to copy just the header. The entire table is copied. How can I target just the header row? The g element? $('#chart_div svg').clone().appendTo($('#movehere'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try cloning the date row and adding to an element above the chart.

the `<g>` element is captured and moved in the original example,
here, we make a copy of it and move to another element...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [
      {id: 'team', label: 'Team', type: 'string'},
      {id: 'start', label: 'Season Start Date', type: 'date'},
      {id: 'end', label: 'Season End Date', type: 'date'}
    ],
    rows: [
      {c: [{v: 'Baltimore Ravens'},     {v: 'Date(2000, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2001, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2001, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2005, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers'},  {v: 'Date(2005, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2006, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Indianapolis Colts'},   {v: 'Date(2006, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2007, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New York Giants'},      {v: 'Date(2007, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2008, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers'},  {v: 'Date(2008, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2009, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New Orleans Saints'},   {v: 'Date(2009, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2010, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Green Bay Packers'},    {v: 'Date(2010, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2011, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Green Bay Packers'},    {v: 'Date(2010, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2011, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2001, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2005, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers'},  {v: 'Date(2005, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2006, 1, 5)'}]},
    ]
  });

  var options = {
    height: 650,
    timeline: {
      groupByRowLabel: true
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', afterDraw);
  chart.draw(data, options);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
});

function afterDraw() {
  var header = document.getElementById('header');
  header.innerHTML = '';
  var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
  var g = svg.getElementsByTagName('g')[1];
  var svgNew = header.appendChild(svg.cloneNode());
  var gNew = svgNew.appendChild(g.cloneNode(true));
  var height = parseFloat(gNew.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].getAttribute('y')) - 25;
  gNew.setAttribute('transform','translate(0,-'+height+')');
  g.parentNode.removeChild(g);
}
```

```css
#header {
  height: 56px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: i love you! This works as expected. I had to comment the "header.innerHTML line and remove the css for the #header in order for everything to work.